# cakePHP Authenticate with associated data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Emails table has: id, address.
Users table has id, email_id, password (hashed)

How do i authenticate a login with this.

```
'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'address',
                    'password' => 'password',
                ],
                'userModel' => 'Users'
            ]
  ]
```

then in login() this is called:

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
if($user){
 //success }
```

Im not sure if this is what i need, or how it processes this to verify

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options){
    select(['Emails.address', 'password'])
        ->where(['Emails.address' => $options['address']]);
```

setting passwords is like this:

```
protected function _setPassword($
    if(strlen($pw) > 0){
        return  (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($pw);
    }   }
```

fyi signup works like this:

```
if($this->Users->save($user))
```

And my form is

```
This form control (emails.address)
This form control (password)
```

Comment: erm... **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750804/validate-user-when-email-and-password-are-in-seperate-tables-cakephp** ?

Comment: that simply doesnt work. things flow through userscontroller now and that works for signup. it just doesnt auth->identify(). is there a way to determine whether the email or password is wrong? or what identify() is. that might help debugging

Comment: Well, what you're showing here is different in crucial points to what I suggested and explained, that's kinda what I wanted to hint. The example I gave you works fine in my tests, and the controller that holds the login action shouldn't matter, there should be no need to do things differently. If authentication fails with the example I posted, then you'll need to do some debugging, starting with check the query that is being generated, and testing whether it returns the expected results.

Comment: The code you're showing _here_ will fail for various reasons, mismatching fields, wrong options being used, missing joins/containments, etc... not to mention that it's syntactically invalid (abstracting things that much in questions usually causes more harm than it helps).

Comment: So what does the SQL query in findauth need to return, is it just the email and password or do I need to do the IDs aswell. Would hashing be automatic here? I'm not sure how to debug and step to the part where it compares pws

Comment: For authentication to succeed, the password field + one additional field are required, it doent matter which one that is, there just needs to be one additional field so that the user data returned by the authenticator isn't empty (the password field will be removed after comparing it). If the request data password would need to be hashed for comparison, this would be done automatically, check the source of [**`BaseAuthenticate::_findUser()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.6/src/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php#L105), `$result` will be the result of the finder query.